Stripe Connect Embedded Onboarding Popup Blocked
I've been following the tutorial for setting up Onboarding with Stripe Connect
https://docs.stripe.com/connect/onboarding/quickstart#init-stripe
I have everything set up, and the iFrame that contains the button to "Add Information" displays on the page, but once i click it, i get a Console Error saying the following:
AccountOnboarding.tsx:133 Uncaught (in promise) SubmerchantAuthError: Popup is blocked by browser.
    at SubmerchantAuthenticationContext.tsx:436:18
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at SubmerchantAuthenticationContext.tsx:431:14
    at SubmerchantAuthenticationContext.tsx:452:14
    at async SubmerchantAuthenticationContext.tsx:580:17

Even so, a popup does open but shows just a loading indicator.
I dug into the code a bit and the issue seems to occur because the call from window.open in the Stripe connect library returns null. I know this can be a problem with window.open when not initiated directly by a user, but i don't see anyone else having this problem with Stripe and React.
Here is my code for this.. perhaps I'm doing something subtley wrong, even though I followed the tutorial:
const createAccountSession = async (accountId: string) => {
  const { data } = await api.post("/payments/sessions", { account: accountId })
  return data
}

const useCreateAccountSession = () => useMutation({
  mutationFn: (accountId: string) => createAccountSession(accountId)
})

const useStripeConnect = (accountId: string) => {
  const { mutate, data, isPending, isError, isSuccess } = useCreateAccountSession()
  const [stripeConnectInstance, setStripeConnectInstance] = useState<StripeConnectInstance>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setStripeConnectInstance(
        loadConnectAndInitialize({
          publishableKey: import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
          fetchClientSecret: () => data.clientSecret,
          appearance: {
            overlays: "dialog",
            variables: {
              colorPrimary: "#635BFF",
            },
          },
        })
      );
    } else {
      mutate(accountId)
    }
  }, [data])

  return stripeConnectInstance;
};

const OnboardSeller = ({ accountId }: OnboardSellerProps) => {

  const stripeConnectInstance = useStripeConnect(accountId)
  const [onboardingExited, setOnboardingExited] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      {stripeConnectInstance && (
        <ConnectComponentsProvider connectInstance={stripeConnectInstance}>
          <ConnectAccountOnboarding
            onExit={() => setOnboardingExited(true)}
          />
        </ConnectComponentsProvider>
      )}
    </>
  )
}


The error message suggests that your browser blocked the popup. Can you enable popup and try again?

I've of course already done this. As I said, the popup does display. And this is not a browser specific problem. This happens in Safari, Chrome, Edge and Firefox - popups enabled in all.
